# Javascript mock a variable inside a method

Tags: javascript, jestjs

I have this object:

```js
import keys from './keys'
const obj = {
  getData: async funcion(url) {
    const key = await keys.getAccess()

    return get(url, {
        secret: key
      }
    })
}
}
```

I want to mock the `key` variable with a mock value. I tried:

```js
test('test', async() => {
  const spyD = jest.spyOn(obj, 'getData');
  expect(obj.getData).toHaveBeenCalledWith('/url', {secret: 'my mocked key') //but secret is undefined
})
```

... but i can't mock the `key` variable. How to mock that variable from my function?

Comment: `let keys = {async getAccess(){ return "my mocked key" }}`

Comment: @pishpish, is not a problem with my function, but with the test, i need to mock that variable, not to change the original data.

Comment: Why would you expect `obj.getData` to have been called with `{secret: 'my mocked key'}`? The inner function `get` is called with that, not `obj.getData`. Perhaps you should be testing that instead.

Comment: @lawrence-witt, i need here `secret: key` to be secret: 'my-key-mock'. This question is something similar with my issue, so i tried to replicate it. Anyway, i need to mock that variable inside the function. Could you help please? This will save a lot of time for me.

Answer (score 1):

You can't directly; the scope is closed over, there is no way to gain access to a variable declared within it. You can pass in the function that creates `key` instead so that you can mock its implementation, while passing the original function as a default:

```
const obj = {
  getData: async function(url, getAccess = keys.getAccess) {
    const key = await getAccess()

    return get(url, {
        secret: key
      }
    })
  }
}
```

```
test('test', async () => {
  const spyD = jest.spyOn(obj, 'getData');

  const result = await obj.getData("/url", async () => "my mocked key");

  expect(spyD).toHaveBeenCalledWith("/url");
})
```

This test should now pass, and `result` will be the return value of `get` called with `"/url"` and `{secret: "my mocked key"}`.

Alternatively, if you would prefer not to modify `obj`, you can mock the implementation of `getData` altogether to get the same result:

```
test('test', async () => {
  const spyD = jest.spyOn(obj, 'getData').mockImplementation(async (url) => {
    return get(url, {secret: "my-mocked-key"})
  });

  const result = await obj.getData("/url");

  expect(spyD).toHaveBeenCalledWith("/url");
})
```

Comment: is there also a solution to use `jest.mock('./keys',() => { //here to mock keys.getAccess() }), without using spyOn after that.?

Comment: could you help?

Comment: I think you're right, although I'm not totally sure what the best syntax would be here. I don't have a good environment set up to test this at the moment so don't feel confident adding to my answer. Take a look at how the [docs](https://jestjs.io/docs/jest-object#jestmockmodulename-factory-options) have set it up.